# Expected Value Given Function to Determine Value of Object and Function For Time of Failure

Tags: probability

> The value, $v$, of an appliance is based on the number of years since purchase, $t$, as follows:
>
> $$v(t)={e}^{7-0.2t}$$
>   If the appliance fails within seven years of purchase, a warranty pays the owner the value of the appliance. After seven years, the warranty pays nothing.
>
> The time until failure of the appliance failing has an exponential distribution with mean $10$.
>
> Calculate the expected payment from the warranty.

So far, I've tried a couple things with limited success: the first would have been to calculate the probability of the appliance failing in the first $7$ years, finding the expected value of the appliance is $7$ years and multiplying these values. Secondly, I tried a univariate transformation which was hugely unsuccessful. I've tried calculating the expected value with bounds $0-7$ for the expected value function with little success. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the lifetime of the product. The quantity we're interested in is \begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[v(X)\mathsf 1_{\{X<7\}}\right] &= \int_0^7 e^{7-\frac15 t}\frac1{10} e^{-\frac1{10}t}\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \frac1{10}\int_0^7 e^{7-\frac3{10}t}\ \mathsf dt\\
&= -\frac13 e^{7-\frac3{10}t}\big |_0^7\\
&= \frac13\left(e^7 - e^{\frac{49}{10}}\right)\\
&\approx 320.78
\end{align}

Comment: E(g(x)), thanks, super easy concept i shouldn't have asked about.